# Bootstrap4: Show / Hide Divs with Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap4 on Rails to make a collapsible menu without using JS. Each menu item is supposed to uncollapse its div and collapse the others.  However, I'm unable to do that. Is there a way to collapse all other divs upon clicking one button?

```
%button.btn.dropdown-toggle{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
  All Stuff
  .dropdown-menu
    %a.dropdown-item{"aria-controls" => "collapseFree", "aria-expanded" => "false", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :href => "#collapseFree"}
      Free Stuff
    %a.dropdown-item{"aria-controls" => "collapseNew", "aria-expanded" => "false", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :href => "#collapseNew"}
      New Stuff
#collapseFree.collapse 
  ..
#collapseNew.collapse
  ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to happen without `js`. You can use a hidden checkbox to show and hide one menu on click but it will not close others. In `css` it's currently impossible to have a parent selector, which is what something like this would require.